# Asymptotics of the sum of squares of Von Mangoldt function values.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

This question was asked in my quiz of number theory and I was not able to make any progress in it.

Question: Show that
$$\sum_{ n\leq x}{\Lambda(n)}^2 = x\log x- x+o(x),$$
where $\Lambda(n)$ is the [Von Mangoldt function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function).

I am sorry but I cannot provide any  attempt for this question  as I am totally struck on it.

I have studied number theory from Introduction to analytic number theory by Tom M Apostol.

Kindly don't close it as this question might be easy for you but it is very hard for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By definition, we know that

$$
\sum_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)^2=\sum_{\substack{k\le\log_2x\\p^k\le x}}\log^2p.
$$

By Chebyshev's inequality, we know

$$
\sum_{2\le k\le\log_2x}\sum_{p\le x^{1/k}}\log^2p\le\log x\sum_{2\le k\le\log_2x}\vartheta(x^{1/k})\ll x^{1/2}\log^2x.
$$

As a result, we have

$$
\sum_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)^2=\sum_{p\le x}\log^2p+O(x^{1/2}\log^2x).
$$

To continue, we quote the prime number theorem in the  form of

$$
\vartheta(x)=x+O\left(x\over\log^Ax\right),
$$

where $A>0$ is any fixed positive constant. Therefore, partial summation gives:

$$
\sum_{p\le x}\log^2p=\int_{2^-}^x\log t\mathrm d\vartheta(t)=\int_2^x\log t\mathrm dt+O\left(x\over\log^{A-1}\right)
$$

Combining everything together, we see that for any $A'>0$ there is

$$
\sum_{n\le x}\Lambda(n)^2=x\log x-x+O\left(x\over\log^{A'}x\right)
$$

Comment: $\sum_{2\le k\le\log_2x}\sum_{p\le x^{1/k}}\log^2p\le\log x\sum_{2\le k\le\log_2x}\vartheta(x^{1/k})$  Can you please elaborate how chebyshev inequality can be used to obtain this?

Comment: In the first sum, we have $\log^2p\le(\log x)\log p$, and the remaining summand explains why $\vartheta(x^{1/k})$ appears on the right hand side.

Comment: I understand. thanks! Unfortunately I am not able to deduce how you wrote,$\log x\sum_{2\le k\le\log_2x}\vartheta(x^{1/k})\ll x^{1/2}\log^2x.$ I looked at related results in the textbook of Apostol but I am not able to find any . Can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: Since $\vartheta(x)=O(x)$, we have $\vartheta(x^{1/k})=O(x^{1/2})$ for $k\ge2$. Thus the actual bound for this sum becomes $\ll\sum_{2\le k\le\log_2x}x^{1/2}\log x\ll x^{1/2}\log^2x$.

Comment: I think partial summation ( Abel's formula) will give $\sum_{p\leq x}  log^2 p = \theta(x)  log(x) - \int_{2}^x \frac{\theta(t)}{t} dt$ not what you mentioned. Can you please elaborate on how you deduced that?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on my comment if you have some time to spare.